# Prove, for every $l \geq 3$ , the $\Big( 1- \dfrac{1}{2 \cdot l}\Big)^{2 \cdot l} < \dfrac{1}{e}$ holds

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, integral-inequality

I need to prove that for every $l \geq 3$, the $\Big( 1- \dfrac{1}{2 \cdot l}\Big)^{2 \cdot l} < \dfrac{1}{e}$ holds. ($l$ is integer)

This is what I tried so far.

$$
\begin{align}
x &= \dfrac{1}{2\cdot l}\\
&\Rightarrow \Big(1-x \Big)^\dfrac{1}{x} <  \dfrac{1}{e}\\
&\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{x} \ln \Big(1-x \Big) < -1\\
&\Rightarrow \ln \Big(1-x \Big) < -x
\end{align}
$$

and I failed to prove the rest of the proof.

Comment: the $l $  is integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$f(x)=\ln(1-x)+x$$
We know, $f(1/6)<0$. Moreover, 
$$f'(x)=1-\frac1{1-x}<0$$
for all $0<x<1$. So, $f$ is decreasing. Thus, $f(x)<f(1/6)<0$ for all $x<1/6$, i.e. $l>3$.

Comment: Thank you very much, There is still some thing vague to me. In logic both $T \Rightarrow T$ and $F \Rightarrow T$ are right. In the proof you get to a $T$ statement (I mean $l > 3$) but how can you deduce that the left side is $T$ or $F$?

Comment: The way you should think of is $$l>3\implies x<1/6\implies f(x)<1(1/6)<0\implies \left(1-\frac1{2l}\right)^{\frac1{2l}}<\frac1e$$

Comment: The problem solved. thanks again